# Wrapping thread based async to task based async

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

How do I wrap code like below in a Task based async method?

```
void ExecuteThreadedAsync(Action a) {
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x=> 
   {
      action();
   });
}
```

Currently, this method is called like:

```
void Method() {
  var context = GetSomeContext();
  ExecuteThreadedAsync(() => 
  {
     var result = TimeConsumingWebServiceCall();
     context.Result = result;
  });
}
```

But what I want is something like:

```
async void Method() {
  var context = GetSomeContext();
  await ExecuteTaskBasedAsync(() => 
  {
     var result = TimeConsumingWebServiceCall();
     context.Result = result;
  });
}
```

Or:

```
async void Method() {
  var context = GetSomeContext();
  var result = await ExecuteTaskBasedAsync<Result>(() => 
  {
    var result = TimeConsumingWebServiceCall();
    return result;
  });
  context.Result = result;
}
```

Comment: Note that `async void` should be used for event handlers only, nowhere else.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what the method `TimeConsumingWebServiceCall()` does - from its name, I infer that it calls a web service and `time consuming` happens due to slow response from the service. This is a IO bound task. Using `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem` or `Task.Run` to synchronously call IO bound task is generally an anti-pattern. You are just offloading work to another thread which is anyway going to synchronously block on the web service call.

`Task.Run` is more suitable to offload compute bound tasks.

In your case, you should investigate how the `TimeConsumingWebServiceCall` actually calls the web service and you should use asynchronous IO API's.

1. Are you using WCF? Choose to `Generate task-based operations` while creating proxy (Add Service Reference).
2. Are you using `System.Net.WebClient`? Switch to the new `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` - start using its asynchronous methods like `GetStringAsync` or `GetStreamAsync`.

This way you can actually leverage the benefit of asynchronous API without un-necessarily blocking threads.

```
async Task Method() {
  var context = GetSomeContext();
  var result = await TimeConsumingWebServiceCallAsync();
  context.Result = result;
}

async Task TimeConsumingWebServiceCallAsync() {
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var results = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(url); // or await wcfProxy.YourWCFMethodAsync();         
    // do processing if necessary
    return results;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the static `Task.Run` method:

```
async void Method() {
  var context = GetSomeContext();
  await Task.Run(() => 
  {
     var result = TimeConsumingWebServiceCall();
     context.Result = result;
  });
}
```

or

```
async void Method() {
  var context = GetSomeContext();
  context.Result = await Task.Run(() => TimeConsumingWebServiceCall());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do in order to wrap a `TimeConsumingWebServiceCall` so that it can be executed asynchronously

```
async void MethodAsync()
{
    var context = GetSomeContext();
    context.Result = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            return TimeConsumingWebServiceCall();
        });
}
```

### A bit more advanced approach

```
async void Method()
{
    var TimeConsumingTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => 
        {
            return TimeConsumingWebServiceCall();
        });
    var context = GetSomeContext();
    context.Result = await TimeConsumingTask;
}
```

The reason behind this is to start the `TimeConsumingTask` even before you invoke `GetSomeContext()` as it can be executed parallely to `TimeConsumingTask`.
When `GetSomeContext()` finishes you `await` for the `TimeConsumingTask` to finish to assign it's result.

Comment: +1 for Task.Factory. As a side note, >> "The reason behind this is to start the TimeConsumingTask" You might want or not want this to happen depending on whether side effects of GetSomeContext() are important for the async operation

Comment: [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2011/10/24/10229468.aspx)